# Header repeat with each record in SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services

I would like to repeat header row with each record fetched in SSRS report. Please help me with the way to achieve the functionality.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you can just add another row into your details row group and type your header names in there.

Answer (score 0):

On the bottom row of the designer which shows Row Groups and Column Groups, there is an arrow down logo at the right side. Click that then it will show Advanced Mode.

Then on the row groups. click the 1st (Static) then on the Properties pane. Make **RepeatOnNewPage** property into True. I also suggest **FixedData** property into true so even if you scroll down, the header still shows.

Comment: Thanks for so much for your suggestion. Aldrin, I don't want to make header fixed or repeat on each page, but if possible wants to repeat header with each record.

Comment: Ahhh I see. sorry I misunderstood your question

Answer (score 0):

Instead of grouping on the row you view as the header simply move into the child group.